# vuejs3: how to init a ref using a prop?

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

I have this codes

```
<script setup>

defineProps({
  position: { type: String, required: false, default: "center middle" },
});

</scritp>
```

I am trying adding this after `defineProps`

```
const myPosition = ref(position);
```

But I got

```
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: position is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong, and, important, why?

Comment: It is documented clearly [in the docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#props-declaration) (don't forget to select the composition API toggle on the left side bar to see the docs for composition API)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To initialize a prop using the "Component" API along with `<script setup>`, you will want to assign the object returned by the `defineProps(...)` macro a name, say `props` and use that variable name when referring to the props in your script. So if you have a prop declared like so:

```javascript
const props = defineProps({
  position: { type: String, required: false, default: "center middle" },
});
```

You can use it in the same script like so:

```javascript
const myLocation = ref(props.position);
```

So, a complete example could look like so:

[image]

## ParentComponent.vue

```html
<template>
  <div class="main-body">
    <h1>Parent Component</h1>

    <div class="grid-container">
      <div>
        Position (in Parent):       
      </div>
      <div>
        <input v-model="msg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div>
        <Child :position="msg" title="Child Component 1"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <Child  title="Child Component 2 (default position property)"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import Child from './Child.vue'

const msg = ref('North West')
</script>

<style>
  .main-body {
    margin: 10px 20px;
  }
  .grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
  }
</style>
```

and then

## Child.vue

```html
<template>
    <h2>
    {{ title }}
  </h2>
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div>
      Position (from parent): 
    </div>
    <div>
      {{ position }}
    </div>
    <div>
      My Position: 
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" v-model="myLocation">
    </div>
    <div>
      My Position: 
    </div>
    <div>
      {{ myLocation }}
    </div>
  </div>
  
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';

const props = defineProps({
  position: { type: String, required: false, default: "center middle" },
  title: { type: String, required: false, default: "ChildComponent"}
});
const myLocation = ref(props.position);  
</script>

<style scoped>
  .grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
  }
</style>
```

Also, please check out this code in the [Vue Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

In this example, the myPosition field is initialized with the prop, but then once the application has been launched, this field is no longer dependent on the prop.

Comment: This answer is  a lot over the need. To fix the problem, from your answer I learned to add `const props =` in front of `defineProps` and then to init the ref using `props.`

Answer (score -2):

At first, you code is not fully enough. Where do you try to `const myPosition = ref(position);`?

If you define your `props` right, then there is no need to apply `ref` or `reactive` to them. They are reactive already.

Simply use now you `position` in the component.

Here is the sample from the Vue Tutorial Step 12 [Props](https://vuejs.org/tutorial/#step-12)

```
<!-- ChildComp.vue -->
<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
  msg: String
})
</script>
```

and

```
<ChildComp :msg="greeting" />
```